# split unity configuration file

Tags: unity-container, configuration-files

I need to split my unity configuration into n different files so i can select it some of those files into the same unity container??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK. It's too late but I could answer. 
You need something like this:

```
    private IUnityContainer ReadContainer()
    {
        var unityCommon = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unityCommon");
        IUnityContainer returnValue = new UnityContainer();
        unityCommon.Configure(returnValue, "Common"); // Unnamed <container> element
        var unitySpecific = (UnityConfigurationSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("unitySpecific");
        unitySpecific.Configure(returnValue, "Specific"); // 
        return returnValue;
    }
```

And have this in app.config:

```
  <configSections>
        <section name="unityCommon" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
        <section name="unitySpecific" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration"/>
  </configSections>

  <unityCommon configSource="unity.common.config.xml" />
```

Comment: A disadvantage of this approach is that in the individual configuration files (e.g., unity.common.config.xml), the root element name must match the element name in app.config (e.g., <unityCommon>), so IntelliSense will not work.

Does anyone know a way around this?

Comment: @ProfK if you look at the history of edits, you'd better know the reason for asking the question !