# c# Wrapper for two different versions of business objects

Tags: c#, .net

Currently I work with two different versions of the internal business objects which have some major differences in the way the API works. When releasing a product which targets both versions of the business objects, I have two separate projects and installers. This leads to a lot of repeated code.

Would it be possible to write a wrapper which would expose a consistent API which could then be used by a single project which could use two different configurations to determine which business objects to use?

**NB** Currently the business objects are provided as a dll which I do not have access to the source code.

Comment: If there are strong similarities between the business objects and business logic, you can use a common interface or object inheritance to cut recoding identical pieces.

Comment: Adapter pattern might also be useful if you would like to wrap the older one to make it "act" like the new one.

Comment: You may be able to resolve this using a wrapper class that in turn uses reflection to call the two objects. That can however become a maintenance nightmare if you have many business objects that need to be addressed in this fashion. Not a great solution, but it is at least an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @jacobRoberts said, you can use DI containers with IOC specifically the one that allows registration via xml configuration e.g. Unity, WindsorCastle etc.

> How it works?
>   You will be using abstraction but not implementation. Means rather than using the Business object class you must use Interface.
>   E.g.

```
public interface IBusinessObj
{
 void DoBusiness();
}

public class BusinessObj1 : IBusinessObj
{
  public void DoBusiness()
  {
    // Your implementation based goes here specific to BusinessObj1 type
  }
}

public class BusinessObj2 : IBusinessObj
{
  public void DoBusiness()
  {
    // Your implementation based goes here specific to BusinessObj2 type
  }
}
```

Now let's go to the consumer class:

```
public class UILayerController
{
 // Here either you can use the Property injection
 public IBusinessObj MyBusinessStuff {get; set ;}

 // OR
 //you can use the constructor injection with private field 
 private IBusinessObj  _myBusinessStuff
 public UILayerController(IBusinessObj  myBusinessStuff)
 {
  _myBusinessStuff = myBusinessStuff;
 }
}
```

Now you need to create a registration class or DIContainer that will help you resolving your instances at run time.

See [this article for using Unity for registration via Configuration or via class.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/488308/UsingplusUnityplusforplusIoCplusandplusDI)

> Update:
>   If you want to use Class Name instead of Interface you can do that with Unity. Just replace the Interface by Business entity class name and keep the injection type as you like in Unity class. Now in the design time configuration you can add something like:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="unity" type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration.UnityConfigurationSection, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.Configuration" />
  </configSections>
  <unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <container>

      <register type="YourApplication.BusinessObjectClass" mapTo="<ProvidedDll1>.<Namespace>.BusinessObjectClass" />

       <!-- For second business class just change the mapping to -->

      <register type="YourApplication.BusinessObjectClass" mapTo="<ProvidedDll2>.<Namespace>.BusinessObjectClass" />

    </container>
  </unity>
</configuration>
```

Here the mapTo attribute will have the complete namespace of class residing in the Business dll.

Now the intialization of Unity container will go like this:

```
UnityContainer container = new UnityContainer();
container.LoadConfiguration();
```

So next time you need to add different implementation. You just need to add a separate unity configuration file for that. 
See this [thread how to split the configuration in separate files for Configurations.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2555539/split-unity-configuration-file)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I have amended my question above, as the business objects are provided as two dlls and I'm not sure that the explanation given above would work in this scenario.

Comment: I need more details to answer to this situation, Does those dlls have same class name for business entity? Can you change the implementation of Consumer class?

Comment: The dlls have the same name and the namespace and class names are also identical. One is just a newer version with extra functionality. Currently I am investigating to see if this is feasible, any code which would use the new dll containing the single API could be changed.

Comment: Now your problem is getting a different scenario so you want to use the Same dll with different version. Is that correct? If yes, you can use binding redirect attribute and just give the version of dll to be loaded and attach any of the versioned dll specified with in range of binding redirect versions. See if that works.

Answer (score 0):

You can write interfaces that your business classes implement and then a factory pattern should get you where you want to be.